# json_encode, json_decode, array?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get into just `data` from

```
{
    "data": [{
        "media_count": 3045,
        "name": "snow",
    },
    {
        "media_count": 79,
        "name": "snowman",
    },
    {
        "media_count": 40,
        "name": "snowday",
    },
    {
        "media_count": 29,
        "name": "snowy",
    }]
}
```

I've been trying, using:

```
$obj = json_decode($res[0], true);
echo $obj['data']; //this returns an array
```

I also tried this:

```
$obj = json_encode($res[0], true);
echo $obj; // this returns json, but not inside `data`

"data": [{
"media_count":54373,
"name":"test"
}]
```

I just want to get inside `data`. How would I do so?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Sorry to mention, I would like this in json format please

eventually, I would like to only see

```
{
    "media_count":54373,
    "name":"test"
}
```

Something like thiat

Comment: Btw, your original JSON, as it stands, is not valid due to the trailing commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to get what you want:

```
$obj = json_decode($res[0], true);
echo json_encode($obj['data']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `$obj['data']` returns an array because that's how the JSON is set up. According to the JSON, data is a collection of elements.

To access within the array, you can do this:

```
foreach($obj['data'] as $object) {
    print_r($object);
}
```

You can also index into it as you want:

`print_r($obj['data'][0]);`

**EDIT**

If I'm getting you correct, you want to convert the first JSON to this:

```
"data": [{
"media_count":54373,
"name":"test"
}]
```

If so, that is not possible since the second fragment is not valid JSON. (use http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: I would like to only index into `data` so essentially, when you echo the new json, `data` shouldn't be there.

Comment: In that case, after `json_decode` do `$obj = $obj['data']`. `$obj` now holds what you want.

Answer (score 0):

firstly access the data item of the json array;

```
    $obj1=$obj[item];
    $sizeobj=sizeof($obj1);

    for($i=0;$i<$sizeobj;$i++)
{
// your code to access the data items
// for eg $obj[item][$i][media_count}
}
```

Comment: So if I try `$obj1 = $obj['data']`, I get this `"`

Comment: $obj1 is not access it is just to find the size of the 'data'